# OCaml error filter list using higher order functions

Tags: list, function, types, filter, ocaml

So I have this exercise:

```
filter (fun x -> x = 0) [(1,0);(2,1);(3,0);(4,1)];;
result int list [1;3]
```

So basically you have to match your x in fun with the second number in list and if its the same you create new list with the first number.

My solution but is wrong

```
   let rec filter f = function
   | []->[]
   | x::l -> if f=snd x then fst x :: filter f l else [];;
```

I get the following error when i want to try the code:

> Error: This expression has type `int` but an expression was expected of
>   type
>            `int -> bool`

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem you report. Here's what I see when I try your code:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# let rec filter f = function
   | []->[]
   | x::l -> if f=snd x then fst x :: filter f l else []    ;;
val filter : 'a -> ('b * 'a) list -> 'b list = <fun>
# filter 0 [(1,0); (2,1); (3,0)];;
- : int list = [1]
```

There are no errors, but it gets the wrong answer. That's what I would expect looking at your code.

Comment: yes, you are right, i forgot to add that f must be like my example not just a number..you can have "(fun x -> x != 0)" or "(fun x -> x > 3)" or anything similar, thanks!

Comment: OK, then `if f = snd x` makes no sense. This compares f (as a value) to the second element of the pair. You want to call f as a function. This would look more like `if f (snd x)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is saying that somewhere the compiler is expecting an `int -> bool` function, but you are giving it an `int`.  The reason you get this error is because you have an equality (`f = snd x`), where `f` is of type `int -> bool` and `snd x` is of type `int`.  both arguments given to the equality must be of the same type.  Instead, what you want to do is simply branch on the result of applying `f` to the second element of `x`, such as:

```
let rec filter f = function
  | []->[]
  | x::l -> if f (snd x) then fst x :: filter f l else [];;
```

That said, I would recommend using pattern matching instead of `fst` and `snd`, such as:

```
 let rec filter f l = 
     match l with
         | [] -> []
         | (x,y)::l -> if f y then x :: filter f l else filter f l
```

Note that `f y` will return something of type bool, which will then determine which branch to take.

Answer (score 0):

Altough Matts answer is right. It's good to just reuse existing functions instead of writing a special from the ground up:

```
[(1,0);(2,1);(3,0);(4,1)]
|> List.filter (fun (_, x) -> x = 0)
|> List.map fst
```